# GeoWebCache won't seed when using a user defined gridset using geoserver 2.8.2

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

Ubuntu 14.04 Tomcat7 Geoserver 2.8.2

I have a WebMercator gridset defined using EPSG:3857 and 15 zoom levels.  When I tell GWC to seed the layer using this gridset it does nothing. If I tell it to use a predefined gridset like EPSG:4326 the task will start and the tiles will be generated without an issue.

The caching demo works for tiled layers using my custom gridset and that will generate individual cached tiles when they are requested but I cannot get GWC to seed it.

My blobstore is specified at:

var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data/data/blobstore/

Also, My custom gridset disappears if I restart geoserver.

```
2016-03-08 16:05:21,720 ERROR [org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder] - Problem communicating with GeoServer
org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheException: Problem communicating with GeoServer
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:575)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:764)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected: RenderedImageMap, got null
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:628)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:569)
    ... 9 more
```

STACK TRACE

```
2016-03-14 12:05:04,510 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,510 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,510 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,510 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,510 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,510 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,510 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,510 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/rest/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,511 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,511 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null with /gwc/rest/**
2016-03-14 12:05:04,511 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid'; to: '/gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid'  and httpMethod= GET
2016-03-14 12:05:04,511 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
2016-03-14 12:05:04,511 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
2016-03-14 12:05:04,511 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - returning ADMIN
2016-03-14 12:05:04,511 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/gwc/rest/seed/GeoNorth:Northern_Clip_PHR_20140730_Pyramid]
2016-03-14 12:05:04,514 DEBUG [org.geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
2016-03-14 12:05:04,515 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-03-14 12:05:04,707 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/web/geowebcache_logo.png, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,707 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/web/geowebcache_logo.png, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:04,707 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /gwc/rest/web/geowebcache_logo.png, QueryString: null with /gwc/rest/web/**
2016-03-14 12:05:04,708 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/gwc/rest/web/geowebcache_logo.png]
2016-03-14 12:05:04,709 DEBUG [org.geoserver.filters] - Not compressing output for mimetype: image/png
2016-03-14 12:05:04,710 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/'
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/rest/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:28,357 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid, QueryString: null with /gwc/rest/**
2016-03-14 12:05:28,358 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid'; to: '/gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid'  and httpMethod= POST
2016-03-14 12:05:28,358 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
2016-03-14 12:05:28,358 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=false
2016-03-14 12:05:28,358 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [POST, DELETE, PUT]
2016-03-14 12:05:28,358 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/gwc/rest/seed/geonorth:northern_clip_phr_20140730_pyramid'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
2016-03-14 12:05:28,358 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - returning ADMIN
2016-03-14 12:05:28,358 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/gwc/rest/seed/GeoNorth:Northern_Clip_PHR_20140730_Pyramid]
2016-03-14 12:05:28,361 DEBUG [org.geoserver.gwc.layer] - --> GWC Seeder Thread-2 submitting getMap request for meta grid location [0, 0, 0] on org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerMetaTile@1d6623f4
2016-03-14 12:05:28,362 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2016-03-14 12:05:28,363 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
2016-03-14 12:05:28,363 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing raster style for GeoNorth:Northern_Clip_PHR_20140730_Pyramid
2016-03-14 12:05:28,366 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms] - setting up map
2016-03-14 12:05:28,373 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - setting up 256x256 image
2016-03-14 12:05:28,377 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error rendering coverage on the fast path
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:344)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:259)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:132)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:505)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:249)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:320)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor296.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:62)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:36)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:80)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor249.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:845)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:275)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWC.dispatchOwsRequest(GWC.java:1223)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:625)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:569)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:764)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 90°00.0'S is too close to a pole.
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1055)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:342)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: Latitude 90°00.0'S is too close to a pole.
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.Mercator$Spherical.transformNormalized(Mercator.java:209)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:897)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:938)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.AbstractMathTransform.transform(AbstractMathTransform.java:237)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.ConcatenatedTransformDirect.transform(ConcatenatedTransformDirect.java:68)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1340)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1408)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope.transform(ReferencedEnvelope.java:688)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope.transform(ReferencedEnvelope.java:634)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.computeReadingGeometry(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:382)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverageInEnvelope(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:290)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverages(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:203)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:800)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:768)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:947)
    ... 43 more
2016-03-14 12:05:28,382 ERROR [org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder] - Problem communicating with GeoServer
org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheException: Problem communicating with GeoServer
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:575)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:764)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected: RenderedImageMap, got null
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:628)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:569)
    ... 9 more
2016-03-14 12:05:28,861 DEBUG [org.geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
2016-03-14 12:05:28,862 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-03-14 12:05:29,325 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/web/geowebcache_logo.png, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:29,325 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /gwc/rest/web/geowebcache_logo.png, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:29,325 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /gwc/rest/web/geowebcache_logo.png, QueryString: null with /gwc/rest/web/**
2016-03-14 12:05:29,325 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/gwc/rest/web/geowebcache_logo.png]
2016-03-14 12:05:29,327 DEBUG [org.geoserver.filters] - Not compressing output for mimetype: image/png
2016-03-14 12:05:29,328 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-03-14 12:05:45,163 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:interface=:15:form::IFormSubmitListener::'; against '/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:45,163 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:interface=:15:form::IFormSubmitListener:: with /web/**
2016-03-14 12:05:45,164 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-03-14 12:05:45,164 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-03-14 12:05:45,164 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-03-14 12:05:45,164 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-03-14 12:05:45,165 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 38 locking in mode WRITE
2016-03-14 12:05:45,165 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 38 got the lock in mode WRITE
2016-03-14 12:05:45,173 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 38 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
2016-03-14 12:05:45,174 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-03-14 12:05:45,316 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage&lines=1000'; against '/web/**'
2016-03-14 12:05:45,316 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/, QueryString: wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage&lines=1000 with /web/**
2016-03-14 12:05:45,317 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-03-14 12:05:45,317 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-03-14 12:05:45,317 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-03-14 12:05:45,317 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - No handler mapping found for [/web/]
2016-03-14 12:05:45,318 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 38 locking in mode WRITE
2016-03-14 12:05:45,318 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 38 got the lock in mode WRITE
2016-03-14 12:05:45,324 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/screen.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-03-14 12:05:45,325 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/print.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-03-14 12:05:45,327 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/geoserver.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-03-14 12:05:45,328 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/ie.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-03-14 12:05:45,330 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2016-03-14 12:05:45,332 DEBUG [org.geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.8.2.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery.inline-info.js to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
```

Comment: That's what happens when you use a GeoServer from the future! (2.9.2 will be released towards the end of 2016 :-p)

Comment: @AndreaAime Thanks for catching that. I'm actually running 2.8.2 Any suggestions?

Comment: You should probably post a full stack trace.

Comment: @AndreaAime Done.

Comment: That is not a full stack trace, it's a log. The Stack trace is what you already posted in the original description, but you cut it short, we'd need to see it fully.